# Difference Colored legends from main plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am using the below code to create legends but I don't know why the colors in legends for various plots are different of devoted to main color of plots

From http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html?q=Inset in Application part:

```
legendPlot[xl_List, d_, args___] := 
 Plot[xl, d, 
 Epilog -> 
 Inset[Panel[
 Grid[MapIndexed[{Graphics[{ColorData[1, First@#2], Thick, 
       Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, AspectRatio -> .5, 
      ImageSize -> 20], #1} &, xl]]], 
  Offset[{-2, -2}, Scaled[{1, 1}]], {Right, Top}], args]
 legendPlot[{Cos[x], Sinc[x], Tan[x], Cot[x]}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

`Sinc` is Orange in the main plot `Tan` is Green, `Cot` is Red!!!!

[image]

Comment: What version are you using? That looks like *Mathematica*'s newer default colors on the plot and the old default colors on the legend!

Comment: Looks like the `legendPlot` is using older version for colors. The first workaround would be defining a new color code and using that color code at both plots.

Comment: I am using version 10 both plot and legend!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an alternative implementation, consider

```
frame[legend_] := Framed[legend, FrameStyle -> Black, RoundingRadius -> 0, 
    FrameMargins -> 0, Background -> White];
legendPlot[xl_List, d_] := Plot[xl, d, PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[
    "Expressions", LabelStyle -> Italic, LegendFunction -> frame], {.88, .75}]];
legendPlot[{Cos[x], Sinc[x], Tan[x], Cot[x]}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

To answer the specific question, the colors in the `Plot` and `Epilog` of the Question are different, because the colors used by `Plot` are not `ColorData[1, ...]`.  Replace `1` by `97` for better agreement.  The complete list of indexed colors can be displayed with

```
MatrixForm[Table[{i, ColorData[i, "ColorList"]}, {i, ColorData["Indexed"]}], 
    TableAlignments -> Left]
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding in exclusions, just for interest.

```
plot = Plot[{Cos[x], Sinc[x], Tan[x], Cot[x]}, {x, 0, 10}];

colourpositions = Position[plot, _RGBColor, Infinity];

colours = Extract[plot, colourpositions];

tanplot = Plot[Tan[x], {x, 0, 10},
   Exclusions -> Map[Pi #/2 &, 2 Range[10] - 1],
   PlotStyle -> colours[[3]]];

cotplot = Plot[Cot[x], {x, 0, 10},
   Exclusions -> Map[Pi #/2 &, 2 Range[10]],
   PlotStyle -> colours[[4]]];

otherplots = Plot[{Cos[x], Sinc[x]}, {x, 0, 10}];

Show[otherplots, tanplot, cotplot,
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-4, 4}},
 Epilog -> Inset[Panel[Grid[MapThread[
      {Graphics[{#2, Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]},
         AspectRatio -> 0.5, ImageSize -> 20], #1} &,
      {Through[{Cos, Sinc, Tan, Cot}@"x"], colours}]]],
   Offset[{-12, -2}, Scaled[{1, 1}]], {Right, Top}]]
```

[image]

Comment: It's very good because the vertical lines of (Tan and Cot) are removed and there is a interval of manual picking of colors